# Создать процесс

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Задача в следующем:

1. Создать процесс из моего приложения
2. Загрузить в созданный процесс dll с нужным мне кодом

Как сделать это грамотно? 
Я хочу создать процесс функцией CreateProcess, затем с помощью родительского процесса загрузить dll в созданный процесс, с помощью удаленного потока, правильно ли я думаю, как сделать лучше и проще?

Answer (score 3):

Вот здесь есть рабочий пример: http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/InjectLibrary/

Только нужно учесть, что начиная с Висты все эти действия будут требовать повышенных привилегий процесса (запуск от имени администратора) и могут (будут?) вызывать срабатывание UAC.

Comment: установка привилегий отладчика прокатит?

Comment: Не знаю, я с инжекцией кода только в XP дело имел.